# Fail to build android Ionic version 1

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an Ionic version 1 project and install Ionic version 4 on my linux machine.

When trying to build an Android using ionic build android e get this error message:

```
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module '/home/myuser/ionic/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js'
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue in latest ionic and cordova versions. try to Run following steps

1. `ionic cordova platform rm browser/android/ios`
2. `ionic cordova run --emulator`

Comment: λ ionic cordova platform rm browser/android/ios
> ionic integrations enable cordova

[INFO] Downloading integration cordova
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 200.132.18.2:8080

    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)

Comment: Now when i try to run : Ionic build, gives me this error message: Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo look at this solution https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2264

Comment: Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.1.2 (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.1.0
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.8

System:

   NodeJS : v8.10.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 7

Environment:

   HTTP_PROXY       : http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080
   http_proxy       : http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080
   HTTPS_PROXY      : https://proxy.mycompany.com:8080
   https_proxy      : https://proxy.mycompany.com:8080
   IONIC_HTTP_PROXY : http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080